# Como cambiar el icono de un boton? Este "fas fa-volume-up" por este "fas fa-volume-mute" nesecito el codigo

Tags: javascript, html5

Como cambiar el icono de un boton? Este "fas fa-volume-up" por este "fas fa-volume-mute" necesito el código

```
<button id="btn5" onclick="myFunction5()"> <i class="fas fa-volume-up"> </button>
```

Comment: Cámbialo con js, modificando su atributo, `elm.setAttribute('class',"fa fa ...")`

Comment: Lo que sucede es que no entiendo del todo christian, pero si me puedes ayudar con el codigo completo te estare muy agradecido, como sea muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Puedes leer la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: te recomiendo dejar el código que tengas del método `myFunction5` para que te den una orientación mas completa.

Answer (score 1):

como te lo indican en los comentarios:

```
<button id="btn5" onclick="myFunction5()"> <i class="fas fa-volume-up"> </button>
```

simplemente el método `setAttribute` te permite sobre escribir o colocar un atributo indicando en el valor de la izquierda, en el ejemplo: `class` y luego tambien a ese método le coloca al atributo el texto indicado en el valor de la derecha en este ejemplo: `"fa fa-volume-mute"`

al final si haces esto dentro de tu funcion `myFunction5`:

```
elm.setAttribute('class',"fas fa-volume-mute");
```

el `HTML` debe quedar así cuando la ejecución es correcta:

```
<button id="btn5" onclick="myFunction5()"> <i class="fas fa-volume-mute"> </button>
```

Documentación:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute